# Unable to create Log Alert using New-AzActivityLogAlert

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation

We are trying to automate the creation of log alerts using the Az.Monitor library and getting the following error
*New-AzActivityLogAlert : The module 'Az.Monitor.internal' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Monitor.internal'.
At E:\Code\Code\ManageLogAnalyticsAlerts.ps1:28 char:5
New-AzActivityLogAlert -Name 'sometest' -ResourceGroupName $logWo ...
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Az.Monitor.inte...ctivityLogAlert:String) [New-AzActivityLogAlert], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule,New-AzActivityLogAlert*

The code that we are using is

```
$receiverName = $actionGroupName 
    $actionGroupReceiver = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name $receiverName -EmailReceiver -EmailAddress 'emailstub@email.com' -UseCommonAlertSchema -WarningAction silentlyContinue
    
    $actionGroup = Set-AzActionGroup -Name $actionGroupName -ResourceGroup $logWorkspace.ResourceGroupName -ShortName $actionGroupName -Receiver $actionGroupReceiver  -WarningAction silentlyContinue

    
    Write-Host '----Action Group: ' $actionGroupName  ', Action Group Id: ' $actionGroup.Id ', created with Action Group Receiver: ' $receiverName ' in the log workspace: ' $logWorkspace.Name

    $activityGroupObject = New-AzActivityLogAlertActionGroupObject -Id $actionGroup.Id  -WebhookProperty @{"sampleWebhookProperty"="SamplePropertyValue"}

    $scope = "subscriptions/"+(Get-AzContext).Subscription.ID
    $condition1=New-AzActivityLogAlertAlertRuleAnyOfOrLeafConditionObject -Equal Ingestion -Field category
    # $condition2=New-AzActivityLogAlertAlertRuleAnyOfOrLeafConditionObject -Equal Error -Field level

    $any1=New-AzActivityLogAlertAlertRuleLeafConditionObject -Field properties.Operation -Equal 'Data collection"'
    $any2=New-AzActivityLogAlertAlertRuleLeafConditionObject -Field properties.incidentType -Equal Incident
    $condition3=New-AzActivityLogAlertAlertRuleAnyOfOrLeafConditionObject -AnyOf $any1,$any2

    New-AzActivityLogAlert -Name 'sometest' -ResourceGroupName $logWorkspace.ResourceGroupName -Action $activityGroupObject -Condition @($condition1,$condition3) -Location global -Scope $scope
```

The line which is causing the error is

```
New-AzActivityLogAlert -Name 'sometest' -ResourceGroupName $logWorkspace.ResourceGroupName -Action $activityGroupObject -Condition @($condition1,$condition3) -Location global -Scope $scope
```

The Powershell version we have is

```
$PSVersionTable                                                                                                                                                                                      
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.628
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.628
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

The Az Powerhshell version that I have is 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this was a bug, and the Azure team will be deploying the fix to production. Here is the link https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/19927 which gives the timeline.